# Google Maps + ActionBar + status bar translucida en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Intento recrear más o menos la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- De fondo el fragment de Google Map
- Barra de estado semitransparente
- ActionBar que se muestre por debajo de la barra de estado

Lo que me encuentro al poner en `styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

La ActionBar me sube y se muestra por debajo de la Barra de estado con la propiedad `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` si la meto en `<toolbar` no hace nada y si la meto al layout padre que es un `RelativeLayout` no muestra despues el mapa por debajo de la barra y se muestra gris.

Teniendo que sea compatible a partir de la Api16 (Jellybean), es decir que si el Android no tiene soporte de barra de estado transparente pues que se muestre opaca.

Tengo entendido que kitkat hacia delante la barra de estado puede ser translucida y a partir de lollipop colorida

Lo que tengo:

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
     </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**styles-v19.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.testmaps.MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Como se me vee

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y añadir la transparencia directo en la toolbar?

Comment: A mi me funciono el fix de esta pagina http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

Comment: @Bourne el final he podido sin recurrir a hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solventado

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**styles-v19.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

**styles-v21.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

**activity_maps.xml**

La solución recae englobar el `toolbar` en un `LinearLayout` y añadir la propiedad `fitsSystemWindows` a `true` para que se ajuste bien

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.webserveis.app.quickmapview.MapsActivity" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```